# Agrupar por fecha de inicio y fin estados de variable

Tags: php, mysql, json, google-chart-api

Estoy trabajando en un gráfico de tipo Timeline con la API google charts pero dependo de un script que crea una tabla nueva ("new_tbl") pero no quiero depender de la creación de esta ya que lo debo hacer manualmente cada vez que quiero actualizar los datos del gráfico:

Este es el script y posterior consulta:

```
CREATE TABLE new_tbl
SELECT A.id, A.codigo_maquina, A.estado, A.fecha_hora,
  @csum := @csum + 
      IF(A.codigo_maquina = A.prevMachine
         , IF(A.estado = A.prevStatus, 0, A.id
             )
         , A.id
        ) rwGroup
FROM(
      SELECT mch.id, mch.codigo_maquina, mch.estado, mch.fecha_hora
        , @prevStatus prevStatus
        , @prevStatus := mch.estado varPrevStatus
        , @prevObsTime prevObsTime
        , @prevObsTime := mch.fecha_hora varPrevObsTime
        , @prevMachine  prevMachine
        , @prevMachine := mch.codigo_maquina varPrevMachine
      FROM (SELECT @prevStatus := NULL, @prevObsTime := NULL, @prevMachine := NULL) AS dummy 
      CROSS JOIN maquina mch
      ORDER BY mch.codigo_maquina
        , mch.fecha_hora
        , mch.estado ) AS A
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @csum := 0) AS dummy 
GROUP BY  A.id, A.codigo_maquina, A.estado, A.fecha_hora;


SELECT id, codigo_maquina, estado, MIN(fecha_hora), MAX(fecha_hora)
FROM new_tbl
GROUP BY codigo_maquina, estado, rwGroup
ORDER BY codigo_maquina, rwGroup;
```

Esto me retorna el siguiente objeto JSON:

```
{
"cols": [{
    "label": "Codigo Maquina",
    "type": "string",
    "id": "Role"
}, {
    "label": "Estado",
    "type": "string",
    "id": "Name"
}, {
    "label": "Hora_Inicio",
    "type": "datetime",
    "id": "Start"
}, {
    "label": "Hora_Fin",
    "type": "datetime",
    "id": "End"
}],
"rows": [{
    "c": [{
        "v": "Maquina 1"
    }, {
        "v": "Fuera de Linea"
    }, {
        "v": "Date(2018, 05, 03, 08, 34, 47)"
    }, {
        "v": "Date(2018, 05, 03, 19, 24, 01)"
    }]
},
```

El grafico queda bien, pero dependo de ejecutar la consulta manualmente..

[image: Timeline]

Puedo formatear un nuevo objeto json de la misma forma pero con código php? o es mejor crear un procedimiento almacenado en mysql?

De antemano, muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda

Comment: Solucionado, he creado un procedimiento almacenado que borra la tabla anterior y crea una nueva, se ejecutará con cronjob.

Answer (score 0):

puedes usar with para generar la primera consulta como una tabla, luego haces el select secundario en base a esa tabla, fíjate en: [Cláusula WITH](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html), colocan como ejemplo:

```
WITH
 cte1 AS (SELECT a, b FROM table1),
 cte2 AS (SELECT c, d FROM table2)
SELECT b, d FROM cte1 JOIN cte2
 WHERE cte1.a = cte2.c;
```

Lo otro sería que consideres implementar inteligencia de negocio en tu proyecto, teniendo tablas específicas para ese tipo de reportes.

Saludos.